# While Loop with Or not evaluating Correctly

Tags: python, while-loop

Trying to get integer to equal 1, 2 or 3, if none then ask question again and ask for input

```
question = int(input("Enter a program 1.Arts 2.Science 3.Engineering: "))

while (question != 1) or (question != 2) or (question != 3):
    print("Invalid input. Please enter 1, 2, or 3");
    question = int(input("Enter a program 1.Arts 2.Science 3.Engineering: "))
```

Loop keeps repeating

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: Typo?  I think you meant to use *and* instead of *or*.  Any given value will *always* "not equal" at least one of those.

Answer (score 2):

you have a problem with the logic, using `or` mean that as long as the number isn't  1,2 and 3 at **the same time** (which is impossible of course), one of the condition will be true, and the loop will run again.
`and` will do a better job (meaning that the number isn't any of 1-3)
but there is a much shorter way to write it:

```
while question not in range(1,4):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(question != 1) or (question != 2) or (question != 3)
```

If question is 1, then it's not 2 or 3.

If question is 2, then it's not 1 or 3.

If question id 3, then it's not 1 or 2.

Therefore, at least 2 conditions will be true even if one happens to be true, given the fact that these conditions are contradicting each-other.

> A or B or C

is true if and only if at least one of A, B, C is true.

In your criteria at least 2 are true. This is why the condition will always be true. And since this condition is the condition for your loop to continue, your loop will run infinitely.

You will likely want to change your criteria to:

```
not ((question == 1) or (question == 2) or (question == 3))
```

or even

```
(question != 1) and (question != 2) and (question != 3)
```

Comment: a small mistake in your fisrt example, should be `not ((question = 1) or (question = 2) or (question = 3))`

Comment: @codingStarter yes, it was a typo indeed. Edited my answer accordingly. Thanks!